# Wifi doesn't work after suspend from sleep

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend

WiFi doesn't work for me after suspend from sleep. Doesn't happen always, but it's annoying because I have to reboot.
Restarting networking doesn't help because I think it's a device init problem.

In the kern.log I see repeated blocks of

```
failed to read firmware dump area: -28
firmware crashed!
failed to wake target for read32
```

and C tracebacks also.

Full kern.log here: https://pastebin.com/bjcBDXn3

Hardware: Dell Inspirion laptop.
wifi info from `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                                                                                                                                                                   
       description: Wireless interface                                                                                                                                        
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter                                                                                                                     
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros                                                                                                                                               
       physical id: 0                                                                                                                                                         
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0                                                                                                                                             
       logical name: wlp2s0                                                                                                                                                   
       version: 31                                                                                                                                                            
       serial: 8c:c8:4b:31:89:59                                                                                                                                              
       width: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                         
       clock: 33MHz                                                                                                                                                           
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-53-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.146 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:91000000-911fffff
```

OS `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

Please suggest any actions I can try next time this happens or any remedies.

Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on `Ubuntu 18.04.5` @ Dell Inspiron 3793. I'd say it's `ath10k`-driver related, but it requires deeper investigation.

Comment: Here is the discussion on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1807974

Comment: And the discussion on Red Hat Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1560973